# Distinct id in pagination in sqlalchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy, pagination

**Problem** 
I want to load different food products on a page which users then can scroll through.
For this I am using pagination in sqlalchemy which works fine.
The problem though is that I have discovered that some products are being repeated and I have trouble figuring out why.
 I.e when I scroll down the page and the next 10 products are being loaded one or two of them are the same as one of the first 10 that was loaded.
I have included a distinct on the ids but it doesnt seem to help. 
What can I do to make sure I don't get duplicate products when I scroll down the page?

**Backend code (Flask/Python)**

```
from sqlalchemy_paginator import Paginator

   def all_products():
    user_id = request.args.get("userid")
    main_category_id = request.args.get("category_id")
    page_nr = request.args.get("page_nr")

    category_product_query1 = Session.query(enjordfoodProducts.id).distinct(enjordfoodProducts.id).group_by(enjordfoodProducts.id).subquery()



    category_product_query = Session.query(enjordfoodProducts,enjordfoodCompanies).filter(enjordfoodProductsToCompanies.product_id  == enjordfoodProducts.id,
                                                                       enjordfoodProductsToCompanies.company_id == enjordfoodCompanies.id).join(
                                                                       category_product_query1, category_product_query1.c.id == enjordfoodProducts.id).order_by(desc(enjordfoodProducts.ranking_value),enjordfoodProducts.id)



    paginate = Paginator(category_product_query,8)
    pg = paginate.page(page_nr)
    products_list= pg.object_list
    total_pages = paginate.total_pages


    all_product_dictionary = []
    all_product_list = []

    for product, company  in products_list:

        all_product_dictionary = {
            'id' :product.id,
            'product_name':product.product_name,
            'product_image':product.product_image,
            'env_value':product.product_env_value,
            'env_value_color':product.env_value_color,
            'created_by_userid':product.created_by_userid,
            'is_category':product.is_category,
            'company': company.company_name,
        }
        all_product_list.append(all_product_dictionary)

    result_dict = {}
    result_dict["all_products_list"] =all_product_list
    result_dict["current_page_nr"] = page_nr
    result_dict["total_page_nr"] = total_pages

    result = json.dumps(result_dict)
    return result
```

**Frontend code Vue.js**

```
<div class="flow"  >
  <div class="flowpost" v-for="(post,idx) in all_products_list" :key="idx" @click="to_product(post.id)" >

    <img class="product_image"  :src="get_image(post.created_by_userid,post.product_image)"      />


    <div :style="{marginLeft:'12%',marginTop:'40%', height:'23px', position:'absolute',color:'white',paddingTop:'0%',fontSize:'13px', paddingLeft:'0%',paddingRight:'0%',width:'50px', borderRadius:'12px', backgroundColor:post.env_value_color}">
      <img :style="{height:'19px', width:'19px'}" :src= "`${publicPath}`+ 'loggaenjord.png'" alt=""/>
      <div :style="{marginTop:'-20px',marginLeft:'54%', color:'white'}">{{post.env_value}}</div>
    </div>

    <div  :style="{marginTop:'47%',position:'absolute',lineHeight: 0.9,  marginLeft:'3%',width:'120px', textAlign:'center',color:'black'}">
      <span :style="{fontSize:'11px', fontWeight:600}">{{post.product_name}}</span> <br>
      <span :style="{fontSize:'9.3px'}">{{post.company_name}}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



  methods:{
      load_all_products(page_nr){
       var self = this
      axios({
          method:'get',
          url: API_URL+ '/all_products' + '?user_id='+this.user_id+'&page_nr='+page_nr ,
        })
        .then(function(response){

            self.all_products_list.push.apply(self.all_products_list,response.data["all_products_list"])
          
            self.current_page_nr = response.data["current_page_nr"]
            self.total_page_nr = response.data["total_page_nr"]
        })
       },
    addmore(){

        if ( this.current_page_nr  <this.total_page_nr ){
          var page_nr = Number(this.current_page_nr) +1
           this.load_all_products(page_nr) 
         }
       }
    },

    mounted(){
    this.load_all_products(1)

        window.onscroll = () => {
      let bottomOfWindow = document.documentElement.scrollTop + window.innerHeight === document.documentElement.offsetHeight;
      if (bottomOfWindow  ) {
        this.addmore()
      }
    }
   }
```